# Make the IK bone only rotate on the x-axis

Tags: rigging, bones

Not sure what I messed up on here, but both the IK and the center bones have the Limit Rotation constraint, with the same values. Now, I want the mesh to only rotate on the x-axis. But right now, it's more like free-for-all. Before I've made a minecraft rig and it works all right. What do I need to fix this?

[image: Weird bends]

EDIT: I figured out, that it may be because the shoulder is frozen in on eposition and won't rotate when you use the IK. Not sure what's up. I tried following this tutorial: [Blender tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZlt6d4nOzA&list=PLda3VoSoc_TRWPzZHPqJlHfS0kOeQzQUQ&index=5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use other constraints in conjunction with IK. You need to use the built-in IK limits. They are in the Bone Data buttons, in the section marked Inverse Kinematics in The Inverse Kinematics section in the properties > Bone panel

[image]

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Do...#Bone_IK_Panel

Comment: It was one way, but a little glitchy. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I did already check it, but I finally managed to get it working exactly the way I wanted. The both values on limit Z must both be 0. Thank you!